# When upload image file to wcf from android, the image file is broken

Tags: android, wcf, image, uploading

I could not post my good question document.
Because, I am new here, So I can't add any image on the post. It is so bad.

Anyway, I try to explain without the images.

I send image file like bottom source code from android. It sends to WCF as stream. There is no problem on it.

```
File file = new File(path);
FileBody bin = new FileBody(file);
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();         
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(this.SERVICE_URI);
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
reqEntity.addPart("imageData", bin);
postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

When I want to see the uploaded file on the server, The widows cannot open.
First, I open the original file property. And I can see all properties of image like width,height, dpi.

But when I open the uploaded image file property, I can see only size of the file.
And then I want to see the files on notepade.
There is difference between the original file and uploaded file.
That is

```
--kpKP7FRpS5aYCWRNH0NHd0tGRj7hs2QYhVai_
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="imageData"; filename="ty-uz.jpg"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

And then I see a tag too on bottom of file as     --kpKP7FRpS5aYCWRNH0NHd0tGRj7hs2QYhVai_--

Android adds the tags on the original image file before sending, And then I can't see it as image.
So What is the problem? I use same WCF on silverlight application, IT runs very well. No problem. Image files uploads orginialy.

But My android application adds the tags in the image file. What is the problem?

Thank you already now...

Comment: I've been waiting your good solutions :)

Comment: The solution is here.
http://antscode.blogspot.com/2009/11/parsing-multipart-form-data-in-wcf.html

Answer (score 2):

I have also a same problem. I've response to client size of file then see that size of file when upload to server is larger then file in client and it had been broken.

I think data had been modify in progress send data to server. So that, way to upload file to wcf service as you apply in client is incorrect. You can reference a [same topic here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/4c86592e-a534-40a4-81ae-7b459b689a9c/)